# How to create/list events in calendars other than default using Google's API for Python?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, gdata-api

Using the [gdata API for Python](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/docs/2.0/developers_guide_python.html), how do I create or list events in a calendar other than the default one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the url of the custom calendar you want to read/write to, and supply it in the event query. This is what I came up with:

```
#define cal_client:
self.cal_client = gdata.calendar.client.CalendarClient(source='Milosz-GCal-1.0')
#initiate calendar service (log in):
self.cal_client.ClientLogin(email, password, self.cal_client.source);
#get url for custom calendar (cal_index):
self.cal_url=self.cal_client.GetOwnCalendarsFeed().entry[self.cal_index].GetAlternateLink().href
#then, to read from the custom calendar:
self.feed=self.cal_client.GetCalendarEventFeed(self.cal_url)
#and to write to custom calendar:
new_event = self.cal_client.InsertEvent(event,self.cal_url)
```